# How to veryify if VPN network encrypt data correctly in Windows 7?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I configured IPSec VPN network on my router and I successfully to this VPN in local Network.
I have now 2 connections under control panel:
Local connection 
My vpn

I configured full data encryption, not authorization only. **It mean:
L2TP with IPSec policy on: "must"**

I was sure that after connecting to VPN I can turn off "Local conneciton" but if I will do it I lost connection.

Than how to verify if Windows 7 is using VPN and encrypt data? I can't be sure now, it can use Local network and send not encypted data and I don't know about this.

Answer (score 3):

Your "Local connection" is your regular (physical) connection **over which** the IPsec VPN tunnel is built. Disabling that interface will completely isolate your windows client from the network; thus the VPN tunnel will go down as well.

You can try using traceroute to verify whether or not your traffic is going through the VPN tunnel. To provide more information we really need more details, like a network drawing, which IP addresses are being used where, the configuration of your VPN tunnel et cetera.